# maven 2 can't deploy jar or war : “cannot find symbol” error in maven

Tags: java, maven

I want to deploy my application in two extension: jar and war.
When I type the command `mvn package`, I had this problem:

```
S:\Plateforme\AppJEE\App>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building App 1.5.2.RELEASE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ App ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 6863 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ App ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 68 source files to S:\Plateforme\AppJEE\App\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] /S:/Plateforme/AppJEE/App/src/main/java/com/SSC/Metier/StatistisquesMessionsImpl.java: S:\Plateforme\AppJEE\App\src\main\java\com\SSC\Metier\StatistisquesMessionsImpl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /S:/Plateforme/AppJEE/App/src/main/java/com/SSC/Metier/StatistisquesMessionsImpl.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 2 warnings
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /S:/Plateforme/AppJEE/App/src/main/java/com/SSC/Services/REST/EvaluationCISRestController.java:[16,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: package org.json
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.569 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-02T14:21:54+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/428M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project App: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /S:/Plateforme/AppJEE/App/src/main/java/com/SSC/Services/REST/EvaluationCISRestController.java:[16,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class JSONObject
[ERROR] location: package org.json
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Configuration of the variable `JAVA_HOME` in my machine:
[image: config JAVA_HOME]

Java build PATH of project:
[image: Java build PATH]

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.SSC</groupId>
    <artifactId>App</artifactId>
    <name>App</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 

        <!-- spring data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <!-- pdfbox -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
           <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.1</version>
          </dependency>

   <!-- itextpdf -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
           <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
           <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>

    <!-- mysql-connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.11</version>
</dependency>

      <!-- Spring security  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

        <!-- ecj for exception "No Java compiler available"  -->
       <dependency>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
             <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

        <!-- for uri:  -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
         <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.2</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     </dependency>

   <!-- For JSON Object -->
      <dependency>
           <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
             <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <!--  send mail -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
     </dependency>

         <!-- apache.poi for export table in word -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
             <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
             <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>   

</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

        <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

       <!-- for problem maven-surefire -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin> 



        </plugins>
    </build>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

---

How to make the `symbol: class JSONObject` is readable for maven?

**Solution for the problem JsonObject:**

I added this line in `StatistisquesMessionsImpl` to solve the problem

`import org.json.simple.*;`

---

I compiled the maven command again: `mvn package`

I had another problem:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field bCryptPasswordEncoder in com.SSC.Services.RMI.AuditConfigRmiService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 55.842 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-02T15:37:17+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/604M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project App: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to S:\Plateforme\AppJEE\App\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

How to solve this problem ?

thank you,

Comment: How do you expect ``JSONObject`` to be available? Your ``json-simple`` dependency doesnt provide it.

Comment: Seems that `JSONObject` is available in `org.json.simple` package in `json-simple` dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I solved the problem JSONObject, but I also have another problem. I updated the post.

Comment: Why are you trying to package the code before it compiles or pass all the test cases?

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. If your first issue is resolved, you may self-post an answer since there isn't one yet, then post a new question for a new issue.

Comment: not related to the question, but PDFBox is at 2.0.6 now.

Answer (score 0):

How to make the `symbol: class JSONObject` is readable for maven?

Solution for the problem JsonObject:

I added this line in `StatistisquesMessionsImpl` to solve the problem

```
import org.json.simple.*;
```

---

To solve the problem of `Field bCryptPasswordEncoder in com.SSC.Services.RMI.AuditConfigRmiService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEn‌​coder' that could not be found.`

I added bean in `AppApplication.java`

```
@Bean 
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

After run the following commands:

```
Mvn clean
Mvn package
```